# Sharepoint Not show search result when page load

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, search-results-webpart

I have Sharepoint 2013 and Employee Directory.
Search page whit 2 webparts (search input field and search results).
Querytext: "{searchBoxQuery}*" to search for parts of words.
How to set to not show result until the user not presses enter or the search button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **question mark (?) operator** - this means that if the variables inside this statement are blank or empty then everything between {? and the matching end brace } will be omitted from the expanded query.

e.g. `{?searchBoxQuery}*`

Excellent write up on this by Mikael Svenson on his blog post [here](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/03/sharepoint-search-queries-explained.html?utm_source=shareconf&utm_medium=pptx&utm_campaign=preso)